# How does this allow list operations to be applied to lists with elements of any type?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, polymorphisms

In *Types and Programming Languages* by Pierce, Chapter 11 is simple extensions of the simply typed lambda calculus with any simple base types. Section 11.12 introduces Lists.

How does the section allow list operations to be applied to lists with elements of any type? Specifically, my confusions are:

- Does Section 11.12 introduce lists and list operations by making use of some kind of polymorphism, or type inference? (The book doesn't introduce type inference till Chapter 22 and parametric polymorphism till Chapter 23.)

  Does "*When we ﬁrst introduced lists in §11.12, we used “custom” **inference rules** to allow the operations to be applied to lists with elements of any type*" in Section 23.4  mean that Section 11.12 makes use of type inference to achieve similar behavior of "polymorphism"?
- Does  "*For every type `T`, the type `List T` describes ﬁnite-length lists whose elements are drawn from `T`*" in Section 11.12 mean

  - that  `List T` is a single literal type name for all possible specific typess for `T`, or
  - that `List T`  should be instantiated differently for different specific types for `T`, e.g.  `List Boolean`, `List Nat`?
- Is `[T]`  part of the  the names of the list operators, e.g. `nil[T]`, `cons[T]`, `isnil[T]`?

  Should `[T]` in `nil[T]` be instantiated differently for different specific types for `T`, e.g. `nil[Boolean]`, `nil[Nat]`?
- Does Section 23.4 use the same type `List T` as in Section 11.12? Where is `List T` defined?
- I think lists are not simple types but recursive types (not introduced till Chapter 20), so why does Section 11.12  cover lists?

Thanks.

> **11 Simple Extensions**
>
> **11.12 Lists**
>
> The typing features we have seen can be classiﬁed into base types like
>   Bool and Unit, and type constructors like → and × that build new types
>   from old ones. Another useful type constructor is List. **For every type
>   `T`, the type `List T` describes ﬁnite-length lists whose elements are
>   drawn from `T`.**
>
> Figure 11-13 summarizes the syntax, semantics, and typing rules for
>   lists. Except for syntactic diﬀerences (List T instead of T list,
>   etc.) and **the explicit type annotations on all the syntactic forms
>   in our presentation**, these lists are essentially identical to those
>   found in ML and other functional languages. The empty list (with
>   elements of type `T`) is written `nil[T]`. The list formed by adding a
>   new element `t1` (of type `T`) to the front of a list `t2` is written
>   `cons[T] t1 t2` . The head and tail of a list t are written `head[T] t` and `tail[T] t`. The boolean predicate `isnil[T] t` yields true iﬀ
>   t is empty.
>
> [image]

and

> **23 Universal Types**
>
> **23.4 Examples**
>
> **Polymorphic Lists**
>
> As an example of straightforward polymorphic programming, suppose our
>   programming language is equipped with a type constructor List and term
>   constructors for the usual list manipulation primitives, with the
>   following types.
>
> ```
> ñ nil : ∀X. List X
> cons : ∀X. X → List X → List X
> isnil : ∀X. List X → Bool
> head : ∀X. List X → X
> tail : ∀X. List X → List X
> ```
>
> When we ﬁrst introduced lists in §11.12, we used **“custom” inference
>   rules** to allow the operations to be applied to lists with elements
>   of any type. Here, we can **give the operations polymorphic types**
>   expressing exactly the same constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most importantly, Section 11.12 does not introduce *polymorphic* lists, but introduces *monomorphic* lists annotated by a type of its elements.

For example, Fig. 11-13 introduces a new term `cons[T] t t`. Here `[T]` is a type annotation, which indicates a type of elements of the list. Note that `T` is a metavariable ranged over types, not an object-level type variable or a type-level abstraction. In other words, it is different statements that "For every type `T`, the type `List T` has property P" and "the type of polymorphic lists `∀X. List X` has property P". See Section 3.1 for details of metavariables.

I think most of your questions are answered in short by the above explanation. The followings are more detailed answers.

#### Q1

- Does Section 11.12 introduce lists and list operations by making use of some kind of polymorphism, or type inference?

Neither. It introduces monomorphic lists annotated by an element type (No need of type *inference*).

#### Q2

- What does *"For every type `T`, the type List T describes ﬁnite-length lists whose elements are drawn from `T`"* in Section 11.12 mean?

`T` is a metavariable. For instance, it implies a type `List Bool` describes finite-length lists whose elements are drawn from `Bool`.

#### Q3

- Is `[T]`  part of the  the names of the list operators, e.g. `nil[T]`, `cons[T]`, `isnil[T]`?

`T` is a metavariable. It may give you an intuition to try typing some actual program which contains lists.

#### Q4

- Does Section 23.4 use the same type `List T` as in Section 11.12?

Yes/No. Both sections try to define the type `List T` as "a type of lists whose elements are drawn from `T`", but they define `List T` individually: `List T` of Section 11.12 is defined in Figure 11-13, and `List T` of Section 23.4 is defined informally in sentences.

> ... suppose our programming language is equipped with a type constructor `List` and term constructors for the usual list manipulation primitives, with the following types. ...

As written in the book, the notation of `List T` is the same, but list-related primitives are defined differently.

#### Q5

- I think lists are not simple types but recursive types (not introduced till Chapter 20), so why does Section 11.12 cover lists?

Chapter 20 describes a type system to handle general recursive types, rather than a specific recursive type (e.g. `List T`). Actually the beginning of Chapter 20 takes `List T` as an example of recursive types.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Q2.    "T is a metavariable. It may give you an intuition to try typing some actual program which contains lists." What will  `nil[T]` be in the object language when `T` is `Bool`?

Comment: (2) Q4: "they define List T individually: List T of Section 11.12 is defined in Figure 11-13, and List T of Section 23.4 is defined informally in sentences." Can Section 23.4 use the definition of `List T` in Section 11.12, or they must be different?

Comment: (3) Q5: Ch11 is about extending System $\lambda_{\to}$ with simple types. Is it correct that `List T` is a recursive type, so is not a simple type? Why is `List T` covered in Sec 11.12 of Ch11?

Comment: Sorry (1) is about Q3.

Comment: (4) Q2: "`T` is a metavariable. For instance, it implies a type `List Bool` describes finite-length lists whose elements are drawn from `Bool`."  Is `List Nat` the same as `NatList` in Ch20?

Comment: @Tim (1) Try typing `nil[Bool]` by your hand. Write a type derivation tree for `nil[Bool]`. Also, how about `cons[Bool] true nil[Bool]`? (2) I edited my answer. (3) Do you mean `List T` should be covered in Chap. 20? Why do you need a reason for that? Is there any reasons why you think the extension by lists is not simple? (4) What do you think is the meaning of "the same" here? Since both type definitions and background type systems are different, some equality (or something) needs to be defined to discuss your question.

Comment: (3) Q5: Termination/Normalization. " research on typed lambda-calculi
is usually concerned with systems in which every well-typed computation is
guaranteed to terminate, whereas most programming languages sacriﬁce this
property for the sake of features like recursive function deﬁnitions" (p2) and "no expression that can lead to non-terminating computations can be typed using only simple types" (p143). So is it correct that `List T` as recursive type shouldn't be covered  in the same chapter 11 as  simple types?

Comment: @Tim Chap. 11 is not a chapter for the simple type system. It's for simple extensions (here "simple" is not a technical term). In fact, Chap. 11 also describes a fix combinator, which breaks the termination property. Also, can you write a non-terminating term of the system of Fig. 11-13?

Comment: Can functions on values of `List T` defined in Sec 11.12 run non-terminating? If yes, isn't that contrary to what Ch 11 is supposed to be about? So I don't know why `List T` is covered in Sec 11.12.

Comment: @Tim Chap. 11 is a chapter for uncomplicated extensions of the simple type system of the lambda-calculus. I don't know why you are stick to the termination property.

Comment: Q1: If I understand you correctly,  in Section 11.12, `List T` is written in the metalanguage, where `T` is a metavariable, and should become `List Bool` `List Nat` in the object language. Section 23.4 looks back at Section 11.12 by saying "*When we ﬁrst introduced lists in §11.12, we used “custom” inference rules to allow the operations to be applied to lists with elements of any type*". If the list types appear in the object language are `List Bool`, `List Nat`, ..., is it necessary to "*use “custom” inference rules to allow the operations to be applied to lists with elements of any type*"?

Comment: Q4: when Section 23.4 introduces `nil : ∀X. List X` and other polymorphic list functions on p346, it says as you quoted
    "... *suppose our programming language is equipped with a type constructor List and term constructors for the usual list manipulation primitives, with the following types.*...". Is `List X` used here defined in p351 via Church encoding? Or can?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98345/discussion-between-nekketsuuu-and-tim).